Error "Illegal number" in Bash Scripting Linux Vim Editor
I wrote this code in bash scripting and can't figure out what the error is.
The terminal say:
15: [:Illegal number: 0+1
This is the code:
#!/bin/bash
min=999
max=0
n=0
num=0
promedio=0
i=0
echo "Ingrese n"
read n
while [$i -le $n] ---> LINE 15 IN THE ACTUAL SCRIPT, HERE IS THE ERROR I CANT FIND
do 
echo "Ingrese numero"
read num
if [$num -lt $min]
    then
        min=$num
fi
if [$num -gt $max]
    then 
        max=$num
fi
promedio=$promedio+$num
i=$i+1
done

media=$promedio/$n

echo "Mayor: $max"
echo "Menor: $min"
echo "Promedio: $media"

I tried many things but as I'm not an expert and I couldn't find any solution on the internet I am posting this question.

Spaces are not optional. [$i and [ "$i" are two different things.

Also, i=$i+1 should be i=$(( i + 1 )); your current code stores 1+1 when what you want to store is 2. The same is true for all the other places you want to do arithmetic operations.

Consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here -- some editor integrations, like bash-lsp, can do this for you if you have shellcheck installed locally on your system.
